# Declaring an Interface with read only properties in C++

Tags: c++, qt

I am converting some C# code into C++.

I have come across the following data type:

```
public interface FooBar
{
     string Name { get; }
     decimal Weight { get; }
     int AgeInYears { get; }
}
```

I want to declare this in my C++ header, but I'm not sure what the best way to approach this will be - any suggestions would be appreciated.

PS: I am using Qt (but new to it), so I am willing to use any of the features of Qt (**Q_PROPERTY, Q_INTERFACE**) etc, if that helps me declare an interface with (readonly) properties.

Answer (score 3):

```
class FooBar {
public:
    QString  getName() = 0;
    double   getWeight() = 0;
    int      getAgeInYears() = 0;
};
```

Don't forget to inherit it as public: `NewClass : public FooBar { ... };`.

You absolutely have to declare it yourself, since `Q_INTERFACE` and `Q_PROPERTY` are used to decorated such declarations and inform Qt that they may be used in wacky Qt ways.

Answer (score 2):

Something like that will do the trick:

```
class FooBar
{
public:
    std::string GetName(){ return _name; }
private:
    std::string _name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do that in C++. The only possibility is to make the properties private and write the accessors. There is no syntax sugar that will do it for you. However, some IDE might generate the code.